# threadPriority vs. qualityOfService

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a bunch of threadPriority and setThreadPriority deprecated warnings that are impacting some formatting.  My research says to use qualityOfService as a alternative, but these suggestions are several years old and don't seem to work in my code.  I've working on this for hours.   Suggestions?

This is my original code:

```
else // Existing thumb image not found - so create and queue up a thumb render operation on the work queue
{
    ReaderThumbRender *thumbRender = [[ReaderThumbRender alloc] initWithRequest:request]; // Create a thumb render operation

    [thumbRender setQueuePriority:self.queuePriority]; [thumbRender setThreadPriority:(self.threadPriority - 0.1)]; // Priority

    if (self.isCancelled == NO) // We're not cancelled - so update things and add the render operation to the work queue
    {
        request.thumbView.operation = thumbRender; // Update the thumb view operation property to the new operation

        [[ReaderThumbQueue sharedInstance] addWorkOperation:thumbRender]; // Queue the operation
    }

     // Release ReaderThumbRender object
}
```

Comment: I assume `ReaderThumbRender` is a `NSOperation` subclass? Is `self.queuePriority` a `NSOperationQueuePriority` type? Also, show us what you tried for `qualityOfService`.

Comment: I think I figured this out, but thank you.

Comment: If you think your findings likely will be helpful to future readers facing a similar problem, then further clarify your question and then [post your own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Otherwise, you might want to just delete this question to avoid people down-voting and/or voting to close it.